# SSIS package - Conditional distribution of record set in control flow

Tags: ssis

I have been working on a requirement which serves the following:

- Fetching record set from an OLEDB source through an execute SQL task.
- These record set is then formatted into fixed width and merged into a single column with the help of another Execute SQL task.
- The formatted data is then exported to a flat file..

Now, the requirement has been changed to have the record set (Originally coming from OLEDB source) exported to three separate flat files (Each with different set of data) depending upon value of a package variable.

e.g If (USER::Instructor = 'DEV') then 5 fields will be extracted to one flat file.

e.g If (USER::Instructor = 'Jerry') then 7 fields will be extracted to another flat file. And so on..

My current challenge is I have to extract different set of data without using expressions in the precedence constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a different data flow task for  file formats that you want to be able to export. So a different task for the 5 field export to the 7 field export.

In the Control Flow, you can choose which of these data flow tasks gets executed based on the value of your package variable.

For example, if you set the Disabled property of the 5 field data flow task to the expression @[USER::Instructor] != 'DEV' , then it would be disabled whenever the instructor was not Dev, and enabled whenever it was dev.

Comment: Though it's a good option, is it possible to implement a conditional selection of fields in the Execute SQL task prior to the data flow, where the formatting of the fields are done! The requirement is bit specific not to use multiple data flow tasks.

Comment: You can set an expression on your oleDb source to select different fields, but it won't work well with downstream components. Each data flow task is supposed to be setup for a specific data flow with a specific set of fields, not a changing set of fields at runtime.

Comment: A simpler way to get the result you want, rather than trying to use the data flow task for something it wasn't designed for, would be to write a stored proc that takes parameter @Instructor, and returns the combined single field that you wish to write to your flat file. Then the ssis package just executes the stored proc, and because there is the same one field in the output, it is possible to use the same data flow task for all instructors.

Comment: And alternatively, you could have the SQL commandtext combine the fields into one in the actual sql query, then you could select from a few different sql queries which all produced the same one field based on the value of instructor. I just think this would be pretty messy compared to putting that logic in a stored proc.

Comment: The one to write stored procedure accepting parameter @Instructor seems to be an appropriate option to serve the need. Will definitely try it out..